# error while interpolating services.base-letsencrypt.mem_limit

Tags: docker, memory, docker-compose

I am fairly new to docker and tried to compse the docker images for the following repository https://github.com/hzi-braunschweig/SORMAS-Docker

`docker-compose up` results in the following error:

```
error while interpolating services.base-letsencrypt.mem_limit: failed to cast to expected type: strconv.ParseInt: parsing "1000M": invalid syntax
```

Any explanation of this error?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be already known. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8772

I don't know if this is the same for you as you don't provide any information about docker and docker-compose

Affects me as well on Linux using Docker 20.10.06 and docker-compose version v2.0.1

Using 1000000 instead of 1000M worked in my case

Comment: Thanks for your replie! Where to use the 1000000 ???

Comment: I used it for the mem_limit instead of 1000M. Using 1000M used to work in older docker-compose versions.